# Building a Terraria Arena

Tags: terraria

Having just started a new game, I fully intend to build myself an Arena for the eventual Eye of Cthulhu fight, and naturally an equally elaborate arena for my Eater of Worlds and Skeletron fights to come.

Bearing in mind that the latter two will be in pre-determined locations (Corruption and Dungeon Entrance, respectfully), how can I optimize my arena construction?

Ease of movement against bosses, as well as suggestions for elegant decorations that won't spoil the utility of these areans, are welcome.

To start things off, I'm aware that a major component of my arena should be platforms that are well-spaced to my jump height, and ensuring it is closed-off from wandering mobs who might encroach upon the battle.  Though preferably, I'd like to open it up for eventual Goblin Army Invasions.

Comment: you kind of answer your own question in your question about what you want... so I'm not entirely sure what your question actually is... where to build it?

Comment: Or alternate ways to build it. Honestly I know the answer already, but I feel like there are better answers than my relatively simple one, and I'd like to encourage people to share their own solutions.

Comment: If you know the answer, it's okay to self-answer your question.

Comment: I think I will.

Comment: A great idea for any arena is to have a small room located just above it with a bed (so you can respawn there if you get killed), the nurse (so you can boost yourself back up to full health after respawning), and a heart statue hooked up to a repeater (pumps out hearts so you can duck in and heal yourself).

Comment: I would build it below the arena myself, with a closed-off door so that you can just pop it open and hop up, and so that it doesn't get in the way of the arena itself.  But good advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Terraria.gamepedia.com has example arena structures for several bosses](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Arena).

The general idea is to make a screenwidth area with a completely flat floor and usually at least one platform to jump on, or a tower of equally spaced, long horizontal platforms for floating enemies like Skeletron or the Eye of Cthulu to avoid their attacks better. Material doesn't matter other than the floor should be solid and you should use wood platforms for the other sections so you can jump up/down at will. Walls are rarely useful for arenas so leave them off unless there's some reason you need/want them. Note that the Wall of Flesh will need a much much longer arena (a straight platform really) than other bosses.

As far as decorations just use anything you want that's a background later item (like beds, torches, anything the player walks over). If it doesn't obstruct your movement it doesn't get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

**Cthulhu Arena**

For a Cthulhu arena (which I also use for my Goblin Army fights), I build a large arena out of wood or stone, roughly 5 stories high with two doors to discourage zombie interference (doors remain open during Goblin invasions).

What you want to do is keep it open-top, with platforms going all across it on the interior.  You'll want it to be at least 30 character lengths (60 tiles) wide, but you can make it larger or smaller as your mood and supplies allow (wider tends to be better).  Place down your floor and platforms 5 tiles apart, and make sure you add torches along the platform as well.  Enough to prevent mobs from spawning within your arena.

**Eater of Worlds Arena**

The ideal situation for an Eater of Worlds arena is the surface, where it will have less of an area to roam around.  You'll want to structure it like your Cthulhu arena with platforms.  Walls MUST be made of stone brick or woood  to avoid thorn growth.

If you would prefer an arena closer to a Demon Alter, make use of the wide caverns that tend to connect the deep pits leading to the Demon Orbs.  You can construct platforms similar to your Cthulhu Arena with the space provided, but you'll want to build a ceiling as well in this case, to block out interlopers from the surface (You may want to do this with your surface arena too, just make sure you then make your arena closer to 8 stories tall to give yourself more maneuvering space).

Surface arenas are preferable, and easier to construct and use Worm Food at, but if you are breaking Demon Orbs, it may be easier for you to get to a makeshift underground arena instead.

**Skeletron Arena**

You'll have a bit of trouble building a proper Skeletron arena with that overhang to the dungeon entrance, but luckily for you, you can just get rid of it!  Knock it out and build a Cthulhu arena at the dungeon entrance.  Skeletron is particularly big, so you may want to make it a few stories taller for added maneuverability.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend making digging it out as big as your sanity can handle use wood platforms so you can jump but put a whole straight down the middle through the platforms and at the bottom have honey for regen,also have heart lanterns and campfires throughout it so you always have regen,then start building it vertically  and at the top make a long line with a small area of wood platforms so you can jump onto it the rest asphalt(of course some of this will have to be done later in the game but its something to work for)p.s. add the nurse and a heart and maybe star statue as well

Comment: Could you explain why you suggest any of these things?